# How to create plot using genoPlotR in R for genomic data (Bioinformatics)

Tags: r, plot, bioinformatics

I’m working on plotting gene orders of two organisms using genoPlotR in R. I have my data downloaded from Nucleotide NCBI database in gb format. My data plots perfectly, however, names of genes appear to be crammed up, and I did not really find a way to make space between them or expand size of segment.

my code is the following:

data files:

```
twelve<-try(read_dna_seg_from_file("//Users/location/12.gb"))

thirteen<-try(read_dna_seg_from_file("//Users/location/13.gb"))
```

annotation files:

```
ann_twelve<-annotation(x1=middle(twelve), text=twelve$name, rot = 30)

ann_thirteen<-annotation(x1=middle(thirteen), text=thirteen$name, rot = 30)
```

comparison file:

```
out144<-try(read_comparison_from_blast("/Users/location/out144.out"))
```

plotting:

```
plot_gene_map(dna_segs=list(twelve,thirteen),comparisons= list(out144),annotations=list(ann_twelve, ann_thirteen), annotation_height=0.8, gene_type="side_blocks",dna_seg_scale=TRUE,scale=FALSE, dna_seg_labels=c("twelve","thirteen"))
```

I have been trying different ways to modify segment size on the plotting code, but was not successful.

Here is how my plotted data looks like:

[image: a]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crossposted on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/121324/).

Use the argument annotation_cex=0.5 (or less) in plot_gene_map function.